# Weekly report depending on weekday SSRS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to create report which on Monday will fill only Monday column, on Tuesday Monday and Tuesday columns etc.

[image: report]

One problem is that reporting day is only 1 day - lets say Friday. I set main report and subreports for each day but it wont work since on Monday there was an event that did not occurred on Friday so it does not appear in my report.

Comment: why would an event from monday appear on a report that only shows friday?

Comment: Since Friday's report can include Monday's data, why wouldn't you include Monday's events on Friday's report?

Comment: Ok i made it and this is my solution. Since it was required for report to have ONLY ONE parameter - reporting date (current date, or date chosen by user) I used that parameter to find week beginning date and week end date that contains reporting date parameter. My MDX query is using 2 parameters - week start and week end dates, this are hidden params for report, which are being calculated and passed to query. And then I have colums grupped by date.

this solved my problem

according to Mike D. question - client want to have on friday full overview of events in 1 report - its not my idea :)